# When I'm trying to use mat tree's nestedControl's expandAll method it generates this error

Tags: javascript, angular

When I'm trying to use mat tree's nestedControl's expandAll method it generates this error. How can I fix this? I will appreciate any help.

error
[image: Error]

Code

[image: Code]

Comment: Also post some relevant code where you think the problem resides.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.